# Question on Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading a book on Discrete Math and came upon this Definition in the Chapter of Graphs which I can't understand. Can anyone help me understand its meaning?

**Definition**: The set of all neighbours of a vertex $v$ of $ G = (V , E) $ denoted by $ N(v) $, is called the *neighbourhood* of $v$. If $A$ is a subset of $V$, we denote by $N(A)$ the set of all vertices in $G$ that are adjacent to at least one vertex in $A$. So, $N(A) = \bigcup_{v\in A} N(v)$.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $N(A) = \bigcup_{v\in A}N(v)$ by "can anyone edit my last sentence"?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. What is the first word that you don't understand? Do you know what a *graph* is? A *vertex* of a graph? What it means for a vertex to be a *neighbour* of another vertex?

Comment: *"If $A$ is a subset of $V$, we denote by $N(A)$ the set of all vertices in $G$ that are adjacent to at least one vertex of $A$"*. Here we are simply defining $N(A)=\left\{x\in V:x\text{ is a neighbour of some }v\in A\right\}$. *"So $N(A)=\bigcup_{v\in A}N(v)$"*. You can verify this last equality.

Comment: Note that when using open neighbourhoods of vertex sets it can be awkward to have some elements of $A$ in $N(A)$ and some not in $N(A)$ as can happen with this definition. I prefer to use a definition in terms of closed neighbourhoods as follows: $N(A) := (\bigcup_{v\in A} N[v] ) \setminus A$, where $N[v]:=\{v\} \cup N(v)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the notion of the neighborhood in graphs, it simply means that $v'\in  N(v)$ iff we can go from $v$ to $v'$  in one go, over some of the edges of the graph. Now, we want to have a similar notion not for a single vertex $v$, but for a set of them $A$. We say that $v'\in N(A)$ iff we can go from $A$ (i.e. from some point in $A$) to $v'$ in one go, over some of the edges of the graph. That is, $v'$ is a neighbor of the set $A$ if it is a neighbor of some elemnt $v\in A$. That's why $N(A)$ is natural to define as $N(a) = \bigcup_{v\in A}N(v)$.

Answer (score 0):

Two vertices $u,v\in V$ are said to be adjacent if $uv\in E$, and a vertex $u$ is a "neighbor" of a vertex $v$ if $u$ and $v$ are adjacent. So $N(v)=\{u\in V: uv\in E\}$ and if $A\subset V$ then $N(A)=\bigcup_{v\in A}N(v)$. Is that more clear?